# Exclamation mark removed as for variable assignment side effect

Tags: windows, batch

I'm trying to process property file and replace some of the properties.
While I managed to implement it with

```
@echo OFF

set "file=my.properties"

(for /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ('type "%file%" ^| find /V /N ""') do (
  echo.%%B
)) > output.txt
```

my.properties

```
password=aoeu!aoeu
```

as a side effect all exclamation marks (!) were removed from result file. Is this a bug in windows batch or am I missing something?

Comment: Is that the complete batch file?

Comment: updated with complete script example

Comment: Can you also add a part of the test file that shows the problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this.

Comment: I can only repo this if I have [DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) enabled

Comment: "When the shell is running in EnableDelayedExpansion mode the ! character is used to denote a variable and so must be escaped (twice) if you wish to treat it as a regular character" from [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)